# Inject bundle into service in symfony 2

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, bundle

Is there a way to inject a bundle into a service?

I would like to write my service constructor like this:

```
<?php
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class MyService
{
    /** @var Bundle */
    private $bundle;

    public function __construct(Bundle $bundle) 
    {
        $this->bundle = $bundle;
    }
}
```

For the `services.yml` I'd like to have something like this:

```
services:
    my_service:
        class:     MyService
        arguments: ['how_can_i_reference_a_bundle']
```

Comment: I need to collect objects on a per bundle basis. Of course I can do this with some string identifiers, but I'd prefer to use something which is already there. But I don't know how to get the bundles.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're doing it wrong. What objects do you need to collect? Other services? Read on working with tagged services: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/tags.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your bundle can be setup as a service like that:

```
services:
    acme_foo_bundle:
        class: Acme\Foo\AcmeFooBundle
        factory_service: kernel
        factory_method: getBundle
        arguments:
            - "AcmeFooBundle"
```